# How to calculate a numerical Fourier transform obtained from NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, fourier-analysis

We numerically solve for the electric potential on a box  which obeys Ohm's law:
\begin{equation}\nabla\cdot(\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\leftrightarrow}{\sigma} \nabla \Phi) = 0, \label{Eqn:OhmsLaw}\end{equation} where $\overset{\scriptscriptstyle\leftrightarrow}{\sigma}$ is the 2D conductivity tensor, and $\Phi$ are the electric potential and 2D current density respectively. The diagonal and off-diagonal elements of the conductivity tensor are given by the functions defined in the Mathematica code. They look like this:

[image: sigmaXX]

[image: sigmaXY]

The first plot is $\sigma_{xx}$ as a function of $r$ and second plot is $\sigma_{xy}$ and everything is radially symmetric. When $\sigma_{xx}$ is zero in that tiny interval the electric potential $\hat{z}\cdot((\nabla\sigma_{xy})\times(\nabla\Phi))$, contours of electric potential are parallel to contour of constant $\sigma_{xy}$ and since it is radially symmetric they should be circles.

Now here is the Mathematica code :

```
omegactimestau[B_] := 4.8 10^-10 B/(1.7 10^-29 3 10^10) 3 10^-4/10^8;

x1[r_] := -12.000000000000016` + 20.000000000000025` r;

(*Define conductivity tensor*)
sigmaxy2[x_, y_, B_] :=Piecewise[{{-1., Inequality[0.45, LessEqual, r, Less, 0.55]}, {0., r < 0}, 
  {1., Inequality[0.6499999999999999, LessEqual, r, Less, 0.75]}, 
  {-12.000000000000016 + 20.000000000000025*r, Inequality[0.55, LessEqual, r, Less, 
    0.6499999999999999]}, {18.849565896451544 - 32.1787625422147/Sqrt[1 + 4.*r^2], r >= 0.75}}, 
 22.918285831105766 - 32.17876254221469/Sqrt[1 + 4.*r^2]]

sigmaxx2[x_, y_, B_] := 1/omegactimestau[B] (10^-3 + Piecewise[{
      {Sqrt[x1[r]] (Sqrt[1 - x1[r]]), 0.6 <= r <= 0.65},
      {-Sqrt[x1[r]] (Sqrt[-1 - x1[r]]), 0.55 <= r < 0.6},
      {0, 0.45 <= r < 0.55},
      {(37.69913179290309` - 64.3575250844294`/Sqrt[1 + 4.` r^2] - 2),
        r > 0.75},
      {Abs[
         45.83657166221153` - 64.35752508442938`/Sqrt[1 + 4.` r^2]] - 
        2, 0 <= r < 0.45}
      }] )/. {r -> Sqrt[(x - Lx/2)^2 + (y - Ly/2)^2]};


(*Solve Ohms law*)

gauss = 1 ;
tesla = 10^4 gauss ;
Lx = 15; Ly = 15;
rad = 0.297986 ;

rectangle = ImplicitRegion[0 <= x <= Lx && 0 <= y <= Ly, {x, y}];
frefine = Function[{vertices, area}, Block[{x1, y1}, {x1, y1} = Mean[vertices];
    If[(x1 - Lx/2)^2 + (y1 - Ly/2)^2 < 100 rad^2 && area > 0.001, True, 
     False]]];
mesh = ToElementMesh[rectangle, MaxBoundaryCellMeasure -> 10^-2, 
   MeshRefinementFunction -> frefine];

<< NDSolve`FEM`

(*eqn[B_]=Inactive[Div][{{sigmaxx[x,y,B],sigmaxy[x,y,B]},{-sigmaxy[x,y,B],\
sigmaxx[x,y,B]}}.Inactive[Grad][phi[x,y],{x,y}],{x,y}];*)
reg = mesh;

brange = Range[0.5, 2, 0.5]*tesla;
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{Inactive[
         Div][{{sigmaxx2[x, y, #], sigmaxy2[x, y, #]}, {-sigmaxy2[x, y, #], 
           sigmaxx2[x, y, #]}} . Inactive[Grad][phi[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] ==
        0, phi[Lx, y] == 5, phi[0, y] == -5}, phi, {x, y} \[Element] reg] & /@
    brange;

(*Plots*)

ContourPlot[ 
 sol1[x + Lx/2, y + Ly/2] /. sol1 -> sol1[[2]], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"], 
 ImageSize -> 650, PlotRangePadding -> None, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 22, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", Contours -> 100, 
 PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image: NumericalSolution]

Having obtained a solution for `phi[x, y]` ($\equiv \Phi(x,y)$) I want to calculate $\bar{\Phi}$ defined as
\begin{equation}
\bar{\Phi} ({r})= \int\,\frac{d^2 q}{2\pi^2}\tilde{\Phi}({q}) J_{0}\left(R_{c}|{q}|\right)e^{i {q}\cdot{r}},
\label{convphi}
\end{equation}
where $\tilde{\Phi}(q)$ is the Fourier transform of $\Phi(x,y)$, $J_{0}$ is the zero order Bessel function of first kind, $R_{c}$ is some constant parameter (for the code above it is of the order 0.1). Essentially the steps are first take inverse Fourier transform of solution obtained from `NDSolve` and multiply by the Bessel function and take Fourier transform of result.

In Mathematica there is no 2d Fourier transform equivalent for `NFourierTransform`.

Is there some alternative for the 2d case?

Edit : This question is edited after being deleted by me because I realized that my previous question had no good answer or that my question was bad. I apologize to the stack exchange and the answer below for bad practice.

Comment: Your code as posted returns an empty plot on my system (MM 13.1 on ARM Mac.)  When I run it as is, it complains about how "{x,y} $\in$ Global\`ToElementMesh[...] is not a valid region specification;  I think this is because you invoke `ToElementMesh` before you load `NDSolve\`FEM\``.  Fixing that problem leads to another error "The PDE coefficient (big mess containing `Piecewise` functions) does not evaluate to a numeric matrix", which I'm not sure how to fix.

Comment: That said:  if you want to calculate the 2D Fourier transform then can't you just use `NIntegrate` to evaluate$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \iint \Phi(x,y) e^{i(q_x x + q_y y)}\, dx\, dy?$$

Answer (score 1):

To long for a comment:

Without `Inactive` Mathematica 12.2 evaluates

```
sol1 = NDSolveValue[{ 
     Div [{{sigmaxx2[x, y, #], 
          sigmaxy2[x, y, #]}, {-sigmaxy2[x, y, #], 
          sigmaxx2[x, y, #]}} . Grad [phi[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y}] == 
      0, phi[Lx, y] == 5, phi[0, y] == -5}, 
    phi, {x, y} \[Element] reg] & /@ brange

ContourPlot[sol1[[2]][x + Lx/2, y + Ly/2] , {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> ColorData["SunsetColors"],
  ImageSize -> 650, PlotRangePadding -> None, FrameStyle -> Black, 
 BaseStyle -> FontSize -> 22, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
 Contours -> 100, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]